# How to make a website load only a certain div(class) to save load time, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

Is it possible to load only a certain div for me It Is

```
<div class="the-container">Demo...</div>
```

If any link on the page Is clicked, I want the whole page to remain the same except for that part of the page using JavaScript plus it should happen In a sliding transition. I've tried searching it on Google but It did not help me as I'm very poor at JavaScript. Please help, Thank You!

Comment: Use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: If you really want to **load** after the click, you probably are going to use Ajax. Otherwise you can hide elements.

Note that is different.

Comment: I thought AJAX and JS was the same thing LOL!

Answer (score 2):

The most common and probably best way to do it is with Ajax. However I will answer with a different solution. It might not be the best but it works, and this answer **doesn't require a server**. This will use jQuery and a plugin called Cycle by Malsup. Instead of using images on the plugin, you can use div's which can contain your content. Then use your links as the pager.

Here is a fiddle with minimal styling: http://jsfiddle.net/gdd49xdf/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentbox">About Content</div>

    <div class="contentbox">Portfolio Content</div>
    <div class="contentbox">Services Content</div>
    <div class="contentbox">FAQ Content</div>
    <div class="contentbox">Contact Page</div>
</div>
<!-- Menu -->
  <div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu2">
      <li><a class="firstli" id="about" href="about">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="firstli" id="portfolio" href="portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a class="firstli" id="services" href="services">services</a></li>
      <li><a class="firstli" id="faq" href="faq">faq</a></li>
      <li><a class="firstli" id="contact" href="contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**jQuery Cycle Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.container').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  1000,
    delay: 5000, 
    timeout: 0,
    //sync:   0,
    containerResize: 0,
    slideResize: 0,
    pager:  '#menu2', 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        // return selector string for existing anchor 
        return '#menu2 li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
    } 
});
});
```

CSS Styling and Cycle effect/s is up to you.

Comment: No! I want that in all the links in all the pages, also it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    </body>
<a href="file1.html">File 1</a> | 
<a href="file2.html">File 2</a>

<br><br>
<div class="the-container">Contain will be load here!</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.the-container').text('Please wait...');
        $('.the-container').load($(this).attr('href'));
    })
})
</script>
```

load() method required server.

Comment: It loads the page header twice and does not show the URL